# What is the recommended architecture for implementing a notification service API with multiple transport options including email and a custom client?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I am trying to implement an API for one of the notification services. Let me explain the architecture.
There is a gateway service that has methods for creating configurations. A person can interact with the service and create a configuration for sending a message via email, for example. Then the person calls the Notify method, which accepts the following DTO:

```
 1. Consumer information
 2. Transport configuration
 3. Message: [type (simple, broadcast), content]
```

The `Notify` method looks at the transport and understands that the message should be sent using the email service, so it sends the DTO to the email service. Ok, so I described how gateway and email transport service work.
However, there is a transport called "client" that has not been implemented yet, and it needs to be designed. The main idea is that the client can be a web application, some Avalonia application, etc. It is clear that delivery will happen through a message broker, but how will it all look? I don't quite understand

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to expose an endpoint that returns the messages for a user, and then your application polls this endpoints (every 5 minutes for example) to get the messages for the currently connected user.

You can also setup some kind of brokers, but that will be far more complicated.

Comment: Polling is good but imagine this situation. I want to send message to you right now and you need to see it right now. Polling can't help in this situation I think

Comment: If you have near real-time constraints, I would recommand long-polling (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). I have setup a websocket architecture once, and it was far more difficult than anticipated. Some network equipments do not let websockets pass, or cut your connection after 4 minutes... And one connected, websockets cannot easily be rebalanced. Long-polling gives the illusion of a websocket, but without all those difficulties. Some libraries provide good abstraction.